# Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/Users/Austin/node_modules/pg/lib'

Tags: javascript, next.js

An issue with next.js

```
  Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/Users/Austin/node_modules/pg/lib'
    Could not find files for /index in .next/build-manifest.json
    ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/Users/Austin/node_modules/pg/lib'
```

I'm having a hard time understanding this error message. I'm using next.js and trying to create different webpages. I'll start the program, running npm run dev, and it will give me this at first:

```
[ wait ]  starting the development server ...
[ info ]  waiting on http://localhost:3000 ...
[ ready ] compiled successfully - ready on http://localhost:3000
[ wait ]  compiling ...
[ ready ] compiled successfully - ready on http://localhost:3000
```

and following that give me this error. What does this error mean? I've found different answers online and none of them have worked so far.

Comment: I guess showing some code would be helpful, as your index page, next.js config.

Answer (score 13):

I've run into the same issue. The message is not super helpful but it means you are trying to run node.js/server side code on the client. For example, my problem was importing my db connection file in one of my front end page components. On the client app, I import `db.js` that is trying to connect to a db, but that db connection requires the `dns` module which is native to node.js. The browser can't execute and then throws the error. This is an easy trap to fall into because the line between frontend and backend code is blurry in Next.js apps.